# Server going down everyday because of out of memory Issue

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I have my test environment server setup which is going down everyday as it goes out of memory. To bring the server back I need to re-start the server every time it goes down.

As there could be a memory leak in my Java application. I did a similar setup in my local system and tried to profile it through tool called Jprofiler by triggering the same automation test scripts which runs on test server. But there are no leaks as what I found by the profiling the results of Jprofiler.

Please suggest me if there is a memory leak in the Java application, then how can I find the memory leak or what could be the other reasons for going out of memory.

Comment: This is complicated because it can be different stuff depending on how you built the system. Have you tried things like virtual ram? Can you reconfigure some of the information to be stored on a file or database even if temporarily? I don't know what the program does so, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what it is that your server does, it's entirely likely that it just accumulates data and never gets rid of it. There doesn't have to be a leak to be an uncharacteristic growth in memory usage.